# Error: The non-abstract class 'ChromeProxyService' is missing implementations for these members:

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I did a pub build this morning and all of a sudden, something that was compiling fine yesterday, with no changes today, is breaking.

```
Failed to precompile webdev:webdev:
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dwds-3.1.3/lib/src/services/chrome_proxy_service.dart:40:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'ChromeProxyService' is missing implementations for these members:
 - VmServiceInterface.getSupportedProtocols
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class ChromeProxyService implements VmServiceInterface {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vm_service-4.1.0/lib/src/vm_service.dart:745:24: Context: 'VmServiceInterface.getSupportedProtocols' is defined here.
  Future<ProtocolList> getSupportedProtocols();
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Precompiling executables... (1.9s)
```

I've done a cache repair, another get to see if there are newer versions, I've done an upgrade just to be sure, but as soon as I hit `activate webdev`, I get the above error.

```
~/Code/dart-sdk-2.8.4/bin/pub cache repair
~/Code/dart-sdk-2.8.4/bin/pub get
~/Code/dart-sdk-2.8.4/bin/pub upgrade
~/Code/dart-sdk-2.8.4/bin/pub global activate webdev
~/Code/dart-sdk-2.8.4/bin/pub global run webdev  build --verbose --output=web:build -- --delete-conflicting-outputs || exit
```

This is my `pubspec.yaml`, not much in there

```
name: blah
version: 0.0.0
description: Blah

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.10.0
  build_test: ^0.10.2
  build_web_compilers: ^2.11.0
  test: ^1.0.0
```

And I'm on `Dart` 2.8.4 (getting the same on other versions of Dart, so not sure if the Dart version has an effect)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's a temp workaround

```
pub global activate webdev 2.5.6
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/1036

https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/1037